# rails generate migration doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am new to Rails, and I wanted to add an email confirmation. I tried this:

```
 rails generate migration   AddEmailConfirmedAndConfirmTokenToUser email_confirmed:boolean confirm_token:string
```

but didn't work it shows this error:

> Running via Spring preloader in process 19269
>              error  mongoid [not found]

Since mongodb doesn't start in my project I am working on without using **sudo** mongod I tried adding sudo before rails generate migration like:

`sudo rails generate migration   AddEmailConfirmedAndConfirmTokenToUser email_confirmed:boolean confirm_token:string`

but instead I get this:

```
/Users/.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:271:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem railties (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
        from /Users/.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:299:in `activate_bin_path'
        from /Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
        from /Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
        from /Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I did some research and was suggested to me to update Bundler but that didn't work either. 
I have no idea how to solve this, any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: What migration? Mongodb/mongoid doesn't need (or have) migrations.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you are saying that I do not need to use this: rails generate migration? I checked this article http://beatscodeandlife.ghost.io/email-confirmation-in-rails/  for reference on how to add an email confirmation in rails.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev So you are saying I should skip part 2 in step 1?

Comment: Maybe something else too.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev could you be more specific please?

Comment: I'd have to read through the whole tutorial and see what other instructions are not supported by mongodb.

Comment: Following tutorials is ok, especially if you're new. But copy-pasting commands/code, blindly, without any understanding what they mean, is not very useful. Before copying a line of code you should ideally try to learn/understand what this line of code does and why it's here. So that next time you'll be able to do this without a tutorial/walkthrough.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev to be honest, I almost understood every line of code that I followed. I am new to rails and I have worked with c# asp.net before where I used migrations and I did not know that mongodb does not need migrations. Anyways thanks for that! :)

Comment: Cheers then! Keep up the learning :)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not need migrations, you can just add a field on the model if it is already created.